# Running background threads with Flask and Gunicorn

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to run background_threads in Flask application and deploying it with Gunicorn

Here is the code I am try to deploy:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import logging
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return True

# Background thread example
def background_task():
    logging.debug("Background task started in thread: %s", threading.current_thread().ident)
    while True:
        logging.debug("Background task running")
        socketio.emit('background_task_response', {'data': 'Background Task Result'})
        socketio.sleep(5)

# Worker initializer function
def worker_init(worker):
    logging.debug("Worker initialized")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    background_thread = threading.Thread(target=background_task)
    background_thread.start()

    bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"  # Replace with your desired host and port
    workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1  # Adjust based on your server's resources
    worker_class = "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker"
    worker_init_fn = worker_init

    socketio.run(app)
```

I expect the logs to print out "Background task started in thread..."

For local development I used `python3 test.py` with the following result (expected):

```
DEBUG:root:Background task started in thread: 140426478286400
DEBUG:root:Background task running
```

However when deploying `gunicorn test:app`, the following is logged:

```
[2024-02-06 21:42:09 +0000] [507571] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2024-02-06 21:42:09 +0000] [507571] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (507571)
[2024-02-06 21:42:09 +0000] [507571] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-02-06 21:42:09 +0000] [507572] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 507572
```

As you can see the Background task is not called upon.

Comment: For some reason if i removed `if __name__ == '__main__':`, the background task runs - not sure why but it solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

When you run with `gunicorn test:app`, gunicorn only load app without run file py, lead not to all functions in `__name__ == '__main__'`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    background_thread = threading.Thread(target=background_task)
    background_thread.start()

    bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"  # Replace with your desired host and port
    workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1  # Adjust based on your server's resources
    worker_class = "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker"
    worker_init_fn = worker_init

    socketio.run(app)
else:
    background_thread = threading.Thread(target=background_task)
    background_thread.start()
    gunicorn_app = app
```

Run `gunicorn test:gunicorn_app`